# Corrupted heap in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, windows-store-apps, heap-corruption

I have a Windows Store App that contains a `ListBox` full of items. There is also an option to filter these items based on certain parameters. For example:

```
foreach(var item in ItemsListBox.item)
{
     ListBoxItem container = ItemsListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
     ItemDC context = (ItemDC)container.DataContext;
     if(context.ShouldBeFiltered){
          container.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
     }
     else{
          container.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
     }
}
```

This filtering process is triggered by radio buttons, where one radio button will enable filtering items by property A and another radio button will enable filtering by property B.

My issue is that if I go back and forth between the filtering options (clicking back and forth between each radio button for testing), eventually the app will crash with the only information being:

```
First-chance exception at 0x776A5624 (ntdll.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x776C1378).
Unhandled exception at 0x776A5624 (ntdll.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x776C1378).
```

I believe this is related to the garbage collection going on as I go between the filters, but I am kind of at a loss as to how to approach this. This type of exception doesn't seem to be caught by any sort of `Try/Catch` nor does using `UnhandledException` events catch it either.

Is there something I am doing wrong in terms of going back and forth between `Visibility.Visible` and `Visility.Collapsed` rapidly that would cause the garbage collector to freak out and try to access memory that belongs to something else?

How do I approach an exception like this when dealing with Windows Store Apps?

Comment: that shouldn't happen in a managed application, you should submit a bug report to microsoft